# how to put Checkbox under Forms in zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following `php` script now i want to put his script in `zend forms`  Here is my code so far :-

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($this->Tagkey as $aResultDataValue) {
        $parents [$aResultDataValue['parent']] = $aResultDataValue['parent'];
        $childs [$aResultDataValue['parent']][] = $aResultDataValue['child'];
}

foreach ($parents as $parent) {
     echo '<div>';
     $parent_value = "'$parent'";
     echo '<div><input type="checkbox" name="parents[]" value="'.$parent.'" id="'.$parent.'" class="parentCheck"/>
     <label for="parents_'.$parent.'">'.$parent.'</label></div>';
     foreach ($childs[$parent] as $child) {
           $child_value = "'$child'";
               echo '<div style="margin-left:15px;"><input type="checkbox" name="childs[]" value="'.$child.'" id="childs_'.$child.'" class="child_'.$parent.'" onclick="checkParent('.$parent_value.','.$child_value.');"/>
              <label for="childs_'.$child.'">'.$child.'</label></div>';
     }
     echo '</div>';
}
```

also i am using some `javascript` code here

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      // add multiple select / deselect functionality
      jQuery(".parentCheck").click(function () {
           var childId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
           jQuery('.child_'+childId).attr('checked', this.checked);
      });
 });
 function checkParent(parentId,childId) {
    if(jQuery(".child_"+parentId).length == $(".child_"+parentId+":checked").length) {
           $('#'+parentId).attr("checked", "checked");
       } else {
           $('#'+parentId).removeAttr("checked");
       }
 }  

</script>
```

this works good for me in `.phtml` page but actually i want to put this code in `zend form` and call like this

```
echo $this->form ;
```

what i can do?

Note :- here Tagkey is :-

```
$tags =new Campaign_Model_DbTable_Tag();
$aResultData = $tags->getTagkey(); 
$this->view->Tagkey = $aResultData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make sub form to each parent and child.

EG :-

!!! zend method name may be incorrect. please find the those methods. This is only way to do your work. Try with form decorators.

code of testForm.php

```
$form = Zend_Form();

foreach ($parents as $parent) {

   $subForm = new Zend_SubForm();
   $subForm->addElement($parent);

   foreach ($children as $child) {
       $subForm->addElement($child);
   }

   $form->addSubForm($subForm);
}
```

Why are you use onclick method in element? Try it using Jquery click function like your another code. :)

Comment: :) I am using  Jquery click function here

Comment: You can use click function again with different class. You are not try it? :P

Comment: :) can YOu please give me more explanation i try sub form but not able to got what i want

Comment: :) Help me today is my submission day, here is my code http://pastebin.com/ZP2KG4Ka

Comment: Sory John. I see your comment now. I can try my best. But I also have dead line today. :(